# Solve absolute value inequation with fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am new to absolute-value inequalities, how can I solve this kind of inequation?

$$ | \frac{x^2-5x+4}{x^2-4} | \le 1 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to solve the following system
$$\frac{x^2-5x+4}{x^2-4}\leq1$$ and

$$\frac{x^2-5x+4}{x^2-4}\geq-1$$
For the first we need to solve
$$\frac{x^2-5x+4}{x^2-4}-1\leq0$$ or
$$\frac{8-5x}{(x-2)(x+2)}\leq0,$$
which  by the intervals method gives $x>2$ or $-2<x\leq1.6$.

The second inequality gives
$$\frac{x^2-5x+4}{x^2-4}+1\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{2x^2-5x}{x^2-4}\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{x(2x-5)}{(x-2)(x+2)}\geq0,$$
which by the intervals method again gives $x\geq2.5$ or $0\leq x<2$ or $x<-2$.

Thus, after solving of this system we'll get the answer:
$$[0,1.6]\cup[2.5,+\infty)$$

Comment: OMG!  Full procedure, clear steps. Awesome!

Comment: @Ravi Prakash Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to $$-1\leq \frac{x^2-5x+4}{x^2-4}\leq 1$$

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent. What to do next?

Comment: @RaviPrakash Solve two inequalities by multiplying through by $x^2-4$

Comment: @siegehalver Okay, let me see. And at last, should I take union or intersection of both solutions?

Comment: @siegehalver at last, should I take union or intersection of both solutions?

Comment: Look at the inequality you started with, both need to be true.

Comment: @siegehalver So, it means the INTERSECTION of solution sets of both inequalities

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle such a question is to square it and then solve the inequality.

Thus, you have $\frac{(x^2-5x+4)^2}{(x^2-4)^2} \le 1$

$(x^2-5x+4)^2 = x^4-10x^3+33x^2-40x+16$

$(x^2-4)^2 = x^4 - 8x^2+16$

Now $x^4-10x^3+33x^2-40x+16\le x^4 - 8x^2+16 $

$-10x^3 +41x^2 - 40x \le 0$

$x(10x^2-41x+40) \ge 0$

Either $x\ge 0 \text{ and } 10x^2-41x+40\ge 0$ or $x\le 0 \text{ and } 10x^2-41x+40\le 0$

Solving the first one gives you $x\ge0$ and $x\le 1.6$ and $x\ge2.5$  The second inequality can never be true because it say $x\le0$ and $x\ge 1.6$ and $x\le2.5$

Giving you the below answer.

If you simplify, you get the $x(10x^2-41x+40)\ge 0$

Then the region where this inequality holds would be $[0,\frac{8}{5}]U[2.5,\infty)$

Comment: This is really a nice way. But to be the best, can you please show me the steps of simplification after squaring?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty simple! Nice! This will be the preferred way when expressions are not complicated in the given     question

Comment: You are welcome